# Any good Wild Fermentation for beer and cider sites, forums, recipes, and or books for beginners

Tags: cider, first-time-brewer, wild-yeast, fruit-wine

I have a few fields with different fruits from grapes to dragon fruits, and I am an amateur homebrewer and want to get into wild Fermentation for ciders, fruit wines and later for beer after I learn the tricks of it. All the recipes I found online for guidance are not for beginners, or if they say they are, they are full of unnecessary info. I have a basic knowledge of winemaking and brewing. So the question is are any good sites, forums, recipes, books for learning the untold tricks, if any, of ciders, fruit wines and wild fermentation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sandor Kratz's Book "Wild Fermentation" is a great resource for all sorts of fermentation.  It primarily covers foods, but there is a chapter wines & meads.

https://www.wildfermentation.com/wild-fermentation/

It's the first "cookbook" I ever read cover-to-cover.